# ReferenceError: Behance is not defined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, behance-api

I am trying to start working with the Behance API, I have following scripts included:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/x1").Include("~/scr/jquery.js", "~/scr/jqueryui.js",));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/x2").Include("~/scr/backbone.js", "~/scr/underscore.js", "~/scr/be.js"));
```

In `be.js`:

```
Behance = {
api_url : 'http://www.behance.net/v2/',
api_key: 'asgasgasgasga9s8g…'
};
```

Then on my page I have this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/x1")
@Scripts.Render("~/x2")

<script>
// Set your API key in be.js
//Behance.api_key = // have set this in be.js

// Users
BehanceUser = new Behance.UserModel({ user: ‘UserName’ });
BehanceUser.fetch();
BehanceUser.getProjects();
BehanceUser.getCollections();
BehanceUser.getWips();
</script>
```

But I am receiving following errors in my Chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Behance is not defined
```

Can anybody tell me where I am making a mistake?

Comment: can we see you calling of bundles in the view?

Comment: First thing to check is that the files are actually loading correctly; take a look at the Network tab in the Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: @ user2675751 sure, have added that in the question.
@AnthonyGrist check it, from network tab as well the files, they are being loaded correctly.